# Аргументы со значением по умолчанию Java/Android

Tags: java, android

В Java я довольно недавно и еще более недавно - в разработке под Android. Смутил один момент

Как задать в методе аргументы со значением по умолчанию? Не очень приятно плодить тонну перегрузок на все случаи жизни.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Не могли бы привести пример?

Comment: @LEQADA, раз уж вы удаляете приветствие, то и историю из жизни ТС тоже удаляйте.

Comment: Или плодите перезагрузки или указывайте значения параметров явно

Comment: Вот здесь один чувак описывает какие есть возможности понаделать необязательные параметры в java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965690/java-optional-parameters Может что и пригодится взамен значений по умолчанию

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8):

Такой возможности нет. Для достижения требуемого эффекта делают так:

```
void init(int a, int b, int c) {
...
}

void init(int a, int b) {
    // Значение параметра с по умолчанию 10
    init(a, b, 10); 
}

void init(int a) {
    // Значение параметра с по умолчанию 10, b по умолчанию 20
    init(a, 20, 10);
}
```

То есть перегружают метод несколько раз (для каждого параметра по умолчанию).

Answer (score 6):

Нет, в Java нет возможности задавать значения аргументов методов по-умолчанию.

Подобный функционал реализуется применением паттернов *Factory* и *Builder*.

Answer (score 3):

Мне, как изначально Java разработчику, сложно представить такой функционал нужен. Иногда я делаю 2, максимум 3 перегрузки и то в основном для конструкторов. Если вам нужна тонна то вы что-то делаете не так.

Я не знаю какая у вас задача, но иногда допустимо подставлять значение по умолчанию если аргумент `null`.