# Значения параметра по умолчанию

Tags: java

Я хочу сделать метод у которого есть параметр, который может принимать одно из трёх значений, причем если его не задавать, то одно из трёх задаётся по умолчанию. Можно ли сделать так в java? И как?

Comment: Можно сделать перегрузку метода, которая будет вызывать существующий метод и передавать ему нужно значение

Comment: Похожий вопрос на русском: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461683/183458, солидный список вариантов на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994104/3432401

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum SomeEnum {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD
}

class SomeClass {
    void someMethod(SomeEnum value) {
        ...
    }

    void someMethod() {
        someMethod(SomeEnum.FIRST);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понятно что значит не задать значение: передать значение null или вообще не передать параметр?

```
private ZNACHENIE something;

void method(ZNACHENIE value) {
    if (value == null) {
        this.something = ZNACHENIE.DEFAULT_VALUE;
    }
    this.something = value;
}

void method() {
    this.something = ZNACHENIE.DEFAULT_VALUE;
}

private enum ZNACHENIE {
    DEFAULT_VALUE,
    SECOND_VALUE,
    THIRD_VALUE
}
```

Comment: вообще не передать параметр