# Как разрешить принимать методу определенные значения? Java

Tags: java

Допустим есть метод, принимающий значение типа String:

```
public static void getValue (String value){
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы метод мог принимать строго заданные значения, например «ONE”, “TWO”, “THREE” и не более?

Comment: создайте `enum`

Comment: вообще никак, но хотелось бы спросить, а зачем вам это?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Аргументы со значением по умолчанию Java/Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461683/%d0%90%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-java-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте enum где перечислите все возможные значения. И передавайте его значение в виде параметра в метод.

```
    enum Values{
      ONE,
      TWO,
      ...
    }

    public static void getValue (Values value){
        String val = value.getName();
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Можно ли как-то в перечислении задать условие  внутри для переменных ONE, TWO минимальных и максимальных допустимых значений?

Comment: ONE, TWO... это классы и по логике в них можно прописать многое, смотря что именно вы хотите там указывать. Приведите пример.

Comment: Чтобы при присвоении значения переменной ONE выбрасывалось исключение, если это значение, допустим выглядит так `ONE < 0 || ONE > 10`

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. ONE это не переменная, а вложенный статический класс, это можно увидеть после компиляции. Напишите более подробно что вы хотите сделать. Как я пока понимаю вы хотите проверить значение value, которое пришло в метод getValue(Values value). Там обычно прописывается условие по enum (switch или if), например `if(value == Values.ONE || value == Values.TWO)`. Можно задавать поля и делать методы в enum, все зависит от того что именно вы хотите реализовать.

Answer (score 6):

Вы можете проверять передаваемые значения в рантайме и на неправильные отправлять исключение [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), специально созданное для этого:

```
public static void getValue(String value) {
    if (!"ONE".equals(value) && !"TWO".equals(value) && !"THREE".equals(value)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            String.format("Argument must be in ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']. Received: '%s'", value)
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Тест:

```
getValue("ONE");
getValue(new String("ONE"));
getValue("TWO");
getValue("THREE");
getValue("FOUR");
```

На `FOUR` будет исключение:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be in ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']. Received: 'FOUR'
    at Main.getValue(Main.java:193)
    at Main.main(Main.java:204)
```

---

**PS.**

Проверку можно немного сократить через [java.util.Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```
if (!Arrays.asList("ONE", "TWO", "THREE").contains(value)) {
```

Или аналог [java.util.List.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) (начиная с `java 9`), который в отличии [java.util.Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) вернет неизменяемый список:

```
if (!List.of("ONE", "TWO", "THREE").contains(value)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, можно выбросить исключение.

```
public static void getValue (String value){
    if (!value.equals("ONE") && !value.equals("TWO") && !value.equals( "THREE")){
throw new Exception (value +"is a wrong value!");
    } else{
// DO something
    }
}
```

Если значений много, то лучше загнать их в `enum` и проверять условие с помощью метода `values`

```
enum enumOFValues {
First "ONE",
// another values
}

String[] strs = enumOfValues.values();

 for (int i =0; i< strs.length(); i++){
  if (!value.equals(strs[i]){
  throw new Exception (value + "is a wrong value!!");
  }
 break; 
} else{
  // Do something 
 }
```

Comment: Объекты лучше проверять на эквивалентность через `equals`, т.к. `==` и `!=` проверяет эквивалентность ссылок объектов, а не то, что внутри они равны. Например, `"ONE" == new String("ONE")` вернет `false`, т.к. у новосозданной строки будет другая ссылка

Comment: Да, Вы правы, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Еще... проверка с `||` приведет к тому, что если передали, например `"TWO"` у вас будет исключение, т.к. `TWO` не `ONE`, это же с переданным `ONE` будет -- на проверке с `TWO` завалится :)

Comment: Все, вроде исправил)) Вот так пиши код не запуская))

Answer (score 1):

```
void getValue(String value){
    if(!List.of("ONE", "TWO", "THREE").contains(value)) return;
}
```